# Local History have no History and I don't know what Happened

Tags: android, android-studio

[image: This picture may define the problem]

My `settings.gradle` file showing this

```
<component name="libraryTable">


<library name="Gra
```

I just opened the android studio and saw this, I tried searching local history but it's empty too.

I also tried to invalidate the cache and restart but it didn't work.

I don't know what just happened 3 of my java files are have XML code instead of java code.
Please if anyone ever encountered this problem can help.

P.S I opened the java file in notepad, it still has my old code.

Comment: Your Hard Drive (HDD or SSD) might be corrupt (damaged). Check other documents (like Word or PDF) if they are damaged as well. If so, then it's your drive.

Comment: No everything is fine. Can you see the icon of home.java and login.java are different does that mean anything

Comment: When I run the application beside having red marks the application is running on the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Try
**Clean Project** and **Rebuild Project**. It may work.

Comment: I tried but didn't work. Can you see the icon of home.java and login.java are different does that mean anything

Answer (score 0):

For me worked this solution:

In Andriond Studio Menu:
File/Invalidate Caches

In this Window:
mark only "Clear VCS Log caches and indexes",
press the button "Invalidate and Restart"

And the Local History was back.
(I have no rights to paste the picture)